# preventing autopostback when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a check box and a continue button on my web page. If the user checks the checkbox then I want to do postback on the server otherwise I want to stay on the page:

```
<input data-theme="a"  id="field_UseAdvancedSearch" type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" runat="server" id="chkAgree" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" data-icon="arrow-r" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" /></div>
```

If the user click on the continue button then I want them to go to next page otherwise they need to stay on the same page. I dont want any post back to occur when the continue button is clicked if the user does not check the check box or if the checkbox is not checked then continue button should be disabled.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is called "validation". WebForms has [built-in support for validation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_validators.htm). You don't want to only do client-side validation as it is easy to circumvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you should use OnClientClick attribute on conditional basis. So for this fix you should use jquery function inside `<head>` tag as follows :

```
    <script>
function myFunction()
    {
        if ($('#field_UseAdvancedSearch').is(":checked")){
           return true;
        }
        else if ($('#field_UseAdvancedSearch').is(":not(:checked)")){
            return false;
        }
}</script>
```

And call from your button as follows :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" data-icon="arrow-r" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" OnClientClick="myFunction();" />
```

Here We are checking if the checkbox is checked or not using jQuery and returns based on that if the checkbox is checked then the user able to postback button else user won't able to postback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is important to validate on the server too or else the user can bypass the restriction.

Comment: The current issue are for auto postback issue. Required field validator not mentioned here so we can use it for the actual approach because validators are used for showing an error message.

Comment: I just want to make sure OP knows that client-side only validation will not prevent someone from going to the next page if they are motivated to do so.