# asp:Checkbox can't checked / unchecked in asp:Panel tag

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I am populating rows for GridView and binding them at the backend.
In every row, there is a column that has a HyperLink with `ID = "Button2"`
After hitting Button2 HyperLink, the modal popup gets "myPanel1" to the screen.
In myPanel1, I have another asp:Panel tag with `ID = "CheckBox1Panel"`
In this panel, I have an asp:Checkbox element.
And I can not check-uncheck this Checkbox element. Its ID is "CheckBox1"

Here is my code

Javascript Code

```
function ShowApproveModalPopup(Id)
{ 
    var modal = $find('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_myPanel1ModalPopupExtender');
    document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_HiddenField1').value=Id; 

    modal.show();
    
    return false;
}

function HideModalPopup()
{
    var modal = $find('ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_myPanel1ModalPopupExtender');
    modal.hide();
}
```

Html code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                            Width="100%" 
                            DataKeyNames="Id" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                            EmptyDataText="<br /><br /><br />File could not be found!<br /><br /> 
<br/><br />" 
                            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                            OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
                            AllowPaging="true" 
                            PageSize="25" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border:0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="OperationPanelTableCell1" runat="server"  style="width:16px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px; border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px;" align="left">
                                       <asp:HyperLink ID="Button2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/02.png" AlternateText="asdf" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle Height="30px" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel1" runat="server" Height="304px" Width="425px" Style="display: none;">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <div id="dialog-mask">
    </div>
    <div id="dialog">
        <div id="dialog-header" class="confirmheader">
            <div id="dialog-title">
                Deneme
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="CloseImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/close.gif" OnClientClick="HideModalPopup()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dialog-content" class="confirm">
            <asp:Panel ID="CheckBox1Panel" runat="server">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClick="OKButton_Click" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"/>
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="No" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="myPanel1ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="myPanel1"
    TargetControlID="myPanel1" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
    CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
    OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

C# code

```
HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("Button2");
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("ShowApproveModalPopup('{0}');", Id));
```

Comment: Maybe this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599465/preventing-autopostback-when-a-checkbox-is-clicked

Comment: I have trited to check the checkbox with javascript but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have found the solution.
I have added a HiddenField in Panel and then gave it's id to TargetControlID attribute of ModalPopupExtender. If you want, you can also use button instead of HiddenField element. And also you don't have to use an inner asp:Panel but in my case i need an inner panel

Last state of my code is as below

```
<asp:Panel ID="myPanel1" runat="server" Height="304px" Width="425px" Style="display: none;">
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<div id="dialog-mask">
</div>
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialog-header" class="confirmheader">
        <div id="dialog-title">
            Deneme
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:right;">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="CloseImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/close.gif" OnClientClick="HideModalPopup()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog-content" class="confirm">
        <asp:Panel ID="CheckBox1Panel" runat="server">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SolutionIsHiddenField"/>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" OnClick="OKButton_Click" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"/>
        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="No" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" />
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

ModalPopupExtender

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="myPanel1ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="myPanel1"
    TargetControlID="SolutionIsHiddenField" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
    CancelControlID="CancelButton" 
    OnCancelScript="HideModalPopup()">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```